# How to remove duplicate values (coordinates) in a list

Tags: python, list

I would like to ask how to remove duplicates in this type of list

```
ppoint=[[1,2],[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,3],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

i tried set() but still makes an error of: unhashable list

```
ppoint=[[1,2],[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,3],[3,4],[5,6]]
fpoint=list(set(ppoint))
print (fpoint)
```

i want to get

```
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,3]
```

i think set() works only on single value idexes, is there any alternative way for this?

Answer (score 6):

You can do like this,

```
In [9]: list(set(map(tuple,ppoint)))
Out[9]: [(1, 2), (5, 6), (3, 4), (7, 3)]
```

Comment: Super pythonic and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use an `if` statement? But if you take a look at the `collections` module, I'm sure ther would be an easier solution.

An `if` statement could look like:

```
for coords in ppoint:
    if coords not in fpoint:
        newlist.append(coords)
```