# How do I remove duplicate points from GeoJSON coordinates in Python? Receiving TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, json, geojson

I have a [GeoJSON file](https://gist.github.com/bkleeman/30647168f521e9510a0ee3bd1a486bcf) with duplicate coordinates stored as nested arrays. Single object for reference, see the "coordinates" property towards the end:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "crs": {"type": "name", "properties": {"name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}}, "features": [{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"original": {"Basin": "Valley and Ridge", "Lithology": "Shale", "Shale_play": "Conasauga", "Source": "EIA", "Area_sq_mi": 3240.58067885, "Area_sq_km": 8393.06542771, "Age_shale": "Cambrian", "Age_color": 1}, "required": {"unit": null, "viz_dim": "Area_sq_mi", "legend": "Tight Oil/Shale Gas", "years": []}, "optional": {"description": ""}, "type": {"primary": "shale", "secondary": "gas"}}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-87.37001800036694, 33.014571999710284], [-87.40415900005101, 33.02085199986492], [-87.32181299995092, 33.09078200035857], [-87.1556450003654, 33.23547099972991], [-87.04042899992734, 33.369561999932664], [-86.95666900036612, 33.44300300031086], [-86.8689999998124, 33.48764400030333], [-86.72767400031411, 33.59278400032282], [-86.50615199977062, 33.63360699988983], [-86.27221800030279, 33.7633590001767], [-86.0292749998697, 33.95005700030741], [-85.65364500010934, 34.20510899976165], [-85.48674699987951, 34.29893200020162], [-85.32838800026164, 34.33198600032085], [-85.19582200040985, 34.413098000151734], [-85.11523100025278, 34.571478000220715], [-85.1240029995949, 34.69609600001083], [-85.02976600007895, 34.92122100030121], [-85.0158389996143, 35.016744000332146], [-84.96455600003074, 35.05100200027126], [-84.9104880002841, 35.04050700010535], [-84.88522600007232, 34.966663999880176], [-84.9080849997126, 34.829821999995815], [-84.92937599990591, 34.597192000205226], [-85.01071799972527, 34.42299399983415], [-85.15765899975534, 34.22100600019924], [-85.21265299996477, 34.164361999669545], [-85.3834629997636, 34.0677709999621], [-85.485048000013, 33.963717000175365], [-85.65833099980517, 33.90826299963804], [-85.85014100044248, 33.88146900022848], [-85.95754299999173, 33.86326899965542], [-86.02704000042596, 33.80956099998609], [-86.06997199971867, 33.730073000042616], [-86.14711699956369, 33.657195000306224], [-86.24724099959798, 33.558865000003706], [-86.32383599962213, 33.51779899977148], [-86.46862800042221, 33.528083000339706], [-86.59074499990832, 33.50300299973619], [-86.68252000019984, 33.42025199969136], [-86.8427049999059, 33.276867000263394], [-87.02894500021725, 33.165200999956], [-87.19579499986818, 33.07244600001068], [-87.37001800036694, 33.014571999710284]]]}}, ...
```

I'm trying to use Python to remove these duplicate points by trying to convert them into a `set` object but keep running into `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. I understand that Python interprets JSON arrays as lists. I've made various attempts to convert the lists into tuples, since you can't use a mutable type as a key in a dictionary, but when I try `set(map(tuple, coords))` or `list(set(map(tuple,ppoint)))` as suggested in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53389236/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-coordinates-in-a-list) I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`.

Full script for reference:

```
# basic script to remove duplicate points from geojson coordinates
# a response to SO post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70071555/how-do-i-create-a-mongodb-2dsphere-index-on-a-document-containing-an-array-of-ar

try:
    import simplejson as json
except ImportError:
    import json

input = '../data/TightOil_ShaleGas_US_Aug2015.geojson'
output = '../data/new_data/TightOil_ShaleGas_US_Aug2015_no_duplicates.geojson'
with open(input, 'r') as f:
    file_data = json.loads(f.read())

with open(output, 'w') as f:
    for feature in file_data["features"]:
        coords = feature["geometry"]["coordinates"]
        set(map(tuple, coords))
        print(type(coords))
```

I'm also experiencing issues even just casting my lists to tuples. When I just run:

```
...

for feature in file_data["features"]:
        coords = feature["geometry"]["coordinates"]
        tuple(coords)
        print(type(coords))
```

I get `<class 'list'>` for each object in `coords`.

How do I remove these duplicates and wind up with a type that I can use in a dictionary to write out as an array to a JSON file?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few ideas:

1. In your second example, the line `tuple(coords)` doesn't alter the `coords` variable.  You probably want to say `coords = tuple(coords)` to have the effect you are looking for.
2. In your first example, you have the same problem with the line `set(map(tuple, coords))`.  You need to assign the result to a variable so you can use it in the rest of your code.
3. In your first example, the coordinates are apparently a list-of-lists-of-lists, but it seems that you are treating them as a list-of-lists.  The top-level list has only one element.  Do you know if that is always the case?  Do you know why there is an extra layer of lists here?  If you knew that the top-level list always had only one element, then you could use something like `coords = set(map(tuple, coords[0]))` but if the top-level list might be longer then you would need to process every element in it as well.